# GROUP BY expression (part of column) instead of whole column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a query:
I need to get the quantity of returns made for each year.

`ReturnDate` is the specific date each member has, when the return was made.
To get the year I'm using `LEFT(ReturnDate,4)`.

It all seem OK so far, but I need the list to show Year, City and the complete number of returns for that city, like:

```
YEAR       CITY        QUANTITY
2011       London      300
2011       Stockholm   40
2012       London      250
```

Now, I'm not getting:

```
YEAR       CITY        QUANTITY
2011       London      200
2011       London      100
2011       Stockholm   30
2011       Stockholm   10
2012       London      250
```

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
 SELECT LEFT(ReturnDate,4) AS Year, City, COUNT(ReturnDate) AS Quantity 
 FROM Member
 GROUP BY ReturnDate, City
```

Comment: LEFT(ReturnDate,4) - why are you storing ReturnDate as a string???

Comment: @AaronBertrand OP may not be. Just using `LEFT` to get the year part (incorrectly)

Comment: I have no idea what the type is. I'm selecting only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
GROUP BY LEFT(ReturnDate, 4), City
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can try using `DATEPART`:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, ReturnDate) AS Year, City, COUNT(ReturnDate) AS Quantity 
FROM Member
GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy, ReturnDate), City
```

Comment: So out of curiosity, why type `yyyy` instead of `year`? :-)

Comment: My finger may be feeling lazy, although I could have just as well used `yy` I suppose.